# Redirect non-www requests to www URLs in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is a simple issue, but I can't seem to find an answer doing some quick googling.

What's the Ruby on Rails way of doing this 301 direct (http://x.com/abc > http://www.x.com/abc). A `before_filter`?

Comment: why do you want www there? what does it give you? Checkout http://no-www.org/index.php

Comment: @James - One common usage of www. is so that you don't need a second "cookieless" domain to serve static content from.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ideally you'd do this in your web server (Apache, nginx etc.) configuation so that the request doesn't even touch Rails at all.

Add the following `before_filter` to your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :add_www_subdomain

  private
  def add_www_subdomain
    unless /^www/.match(request.host)
      redirect_to("#{request.protocol}x.com#{request.request_uri}",
                  :status => 301)
    end
  end
end
```

If you did want to do the redirect using Apache, you could use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.x\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.x.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Great answer John. If you are using Rails >= 2.3, I would suggest to use a Metal instead. :)

Comment: For a 301 redirect in the code above, you need to include the status.  Otherwise it's just a 302 Temporary Redirect.

redirect_to("#{request.protocol}x.com#{request.request_uri}", :status=>301)

Comment: I really think this should be best done in the server config as you said in apache, not in Rails. No reason to have this code in your rails app when it more optimally done on the http server (Nginx, Apache...).

Comment: Rails 3.2 and above routing is the better solution.  Use the `redirect` option for `match` to do the proper HTTP 301 redirect to the "canonical" page.  If that page may be several of the same, (e.g. `search?page=2&count=10`) then make sure to add the correct "canonical" links to the head of your document.

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr You don't say why it is the better solution. I can see that there are maintenance benefits to keeping everything in Rails, but there are also performance benefits to bypassing the Rails stack completely for some things.

Comment: @JohnTopley Fair enough.  Here's why: having just completed a major overhaul of canonicalization/redirection of URLs on a large Rails site, we're not seeing significant performance differences from when we did standard Apache redirection (perhaps 1 or 2ms).  Our case, at least is complex: we have https, a multi-tenant application (customer.example.com and www.example.com redirect to example.com, but are handled differently) and so on.  In my experience maintaining rewrites/redirects in Apache becomes cumbersome.  Rails routing provides excellent facilities for all of these nuances.

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr Thanks. It's interesting to learn that there's not much performance difference nowadays.

Comment: `request.fullpath` is for Rails 3+ what used to be `request.request_uri` for Rails 2.

Answer (score 9):

For rails 4, use it -

```
  before_filter :add_www_subdomain

  private
  def add_www_subdomain
    unless /^www/.match(request.host)
      redirect_to("#{request.protocol}www.#{request.host_with_port}",status: 301)
    end
  end
```

Comment: this discards the URL path

Comment: yep, it redirects to homepage, so not very useful :(

Answer (score 7):

While John's answer is perfectly fine, if you are using Rails >= 2.3 I would suggest to create a new Metal. [Rails Metals](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2008/12/17/introducing-rails-metal) are more efficient and they offers better performance.

```
$ ruby script/generate metal NotWwwToWww
```

Then open the file and paste the following code.

```
# Allow the metal piece to run in isolation
require(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config/environment") unless defined?(Rails)

class NotWwwToWww
  def self.call(env)
    if env["HTTP_HOST"] != 'www.example.org'
      [301, {"Content-Type" => "text/html", "Location" => "www.#{env["HTTP_HOST"]}"}, ["Redirecting..."]]
    else
      [404, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Not Found"]]
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, you can customize further the Metal.

If you want to use Apache, [here's a few configurations](http://www.searchmarketingarena.com/questions/243/how-to-301-redirect-non-www-to-www-version).

Comment: Simone, any advice on how to use this with Rails 3? I'd like to redirect `www.foo.com` to `foo.com`.

Comment: With Rails 3 it's even more easier: use the routing `redirect` method. No need to use a Metal.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better Rails 3 way - put this in your `routes.rb` file:

```
  constraints(:host => "example.com") do
    # Won't match root path without brackets around "*x". (using Rails 3.0.3)
    match "(*x)" => redirect { |params, request|
      URI.parse(request.url).tap { |x| x.host = "www.example.com" }.to_s
    }
  end
```

**Update**

Here is how to make it domain agnostic:

```
  constraints(subdomain: '') do
    match "(*x)" => redirect do |params, request|
      URI.parse(request.url).tap { |x| x.host = "www.#{x.host}" }.to_s
    end
  end
```

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution might be to use the [rack-canonical-host gem](https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host), which has a lot of additional flexibility.  Adding a line to config.ru:

```
use Rack::CanonicalHost, 'www.example.com', if: 'example.com'
```

will redirect to *www.example.com* only if the host matches *example.com*. Lots of other examples in the github README.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article when trying to achieve the opposite (www to root domain redirection).
So I wrote the piece of code that [redirects all pages from www to the root domain](http://aymeric.gaurat.net/index.php/2010/how-to-redirect-all-your-pages-from-www-to-root-domain-using-ruby-on-rails/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code -

```
location / {
  if ($http_host ~* "^example.com"){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 redirect;
  }
}
```