# 301 redirect of entire site in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-301

I am going to move my web application to a new domain name and want to use 301 permanent redirect for all incoming traffic to the old domain name.
I was going to use a before_filter in the application controller that does a permanent redirect.  I was wondering how exactly I would write this to catch all urls and pass them 'as is' to the new domain name.

I am aware this can be done through apache or higher level, but I wanted to know how I would do this from the web application if I needed to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reroute old content (.html/.php etc.) to Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063892/reroute-old-content-html-php-etc-to-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1):

If you can, delegate the job to your web server. Don't use Rails.
Otherwise, use Rack Metal.

See

- [Reroute old content (.html/.php etc.) to Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063892/reroute-old-content-html-php-etc-to-ruby-on-rails)
- [Redirect non-www requests to www urls in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706247/redirect-non-www-requests-to-www-urls-in-rails)