# 301 Redirect for ROR Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

There are tons of directions for 301 Redirects for ROR but I can't find one for the 'pages'.  I have applied the following code into .htacess and it doesn't seem to be working.

Redirect 301 /Maui/Maui-snorkeling-and-scuba/activity/MS10-maui-snorkeling-tours http://www.hawaiifunplanner.com/maui/maui-snorkeling-and-scuba/activity/MS10-maui-snorkeling-tours

Any help would be greatly appreciate since I have to do about 30 redirects due to duplicate keyword descriptions.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reroute old content (.html/.php etc.) to Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063892/reroute-old-content-html-php-etc-to-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1):

see: http://www.camelpunch.com/web-development/tutorials/301-redirect-with-rails/