# 301 Redirect old php-paths to new Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, redirect

I am remaking an old php website into RubyOnRails (3.0.3). The existing website (written in php) has been online for some years now and gained a lot of links and is well positioned in Google.

Now, since I am releasing it in Rails on the same domain I want the old files to be 301 redirected to the corresponding file in the new version. What would be the best way?

These are the circumstances:

- I am building the new website on the same domain where I am replacing the php-version
- There is no logic in how the files have been renamed. For example www.domain.com/cat/home/page/helloworld.php might have its corresponding place at www.domain.com/stuff/hello-world-in-rails and some files have been removed etc.
- Thus, I would like to specify in a table, or similar, where one column is the old path and the other column is the new path. When someone tries to access www.domain.com/cat/home/page/helloworld.php they will be 301:d to www.domain.com/stuff/hello-world-in-rails

When I have made php-sites into Wordpress I have solved this by adding a redirect code in each php file pointing to the new path (in Wordpress). Since my Rails-installation doesn't support php-files, this is not possible however.

I assume mod_rewrite is my weapon of choice, but how should I go at it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reroute old content (.html/.php etc.) to Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063892/reroute-old-content-html-php-etc-to-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage all the redirections in the routes file. Here the documentation f the routes, espacially the redirct method will be interresting for you!

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Comment: Yes, this works fine. I didn't realize it was that simple! But are they being 301 redirected?

Comment: I think you can give the HTTP Code as param to the method. Check the documentation I think there is an option called :status which gives you the possibility to change the HTTP status.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest handling this task with Rack, Should be quick and take the load off your rails app.

There is a rubygem for rack called '[redirect](https://github.com/p8/redirect/)'

It allows you to detect and redirect certain urls using a simple array. e.g.

```
redirect  ['/catch_url', '/redirect_url'],
          ['/catch_url2', '/redirect_url2']
```

NOTE: repo has not been updated in a while, so not sure if it's still working, even if it isn't, there is not too much code in it and you could probably roll your own adjusted version of it pretty easily if needed.