# How do I redirect without www using Rails 3 / Rack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, rack

I understand there are a lot of questions that answer this. I'm familiar with `.htaccess` and `nginx.conf` methods, but I do not have access to such traditional configuration methods on Heroku.

[Simone Carletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123527/simone-carletti) gave this answer that leverages Rails 2.x Metals, but **I'm using Rails 3** and this isn't compatible:

*[Redirect non-www requests to www URLs in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706247/redirect-non-www-requests-to-www-urls-in-rails/1706312#1706312)*

#### Please note:

I'm not looking for a simple `before_filter` in my ApplicationController. I'd like to accomplish a rewrite similar to Simone's. I believe this is job for the webserver or middleware like Rack at the very least, so I'd like to leave this bit out of the actual application code.

### Goal

```
redirect                to                  status
----------------------------------------------------
www.foo.com             foo.com             301
www.foo.com/whatever    foo.com/whatever    301
```

**Only** hosts matching `/^www\./` should be redirected. All other requests should be ignored.

Comment: I don't understand the need for the each method. My middlewares don't have it, and they work like a charm.

Comment: Ah, now I see: self is returned as the response body in the redirection case, and the body must respond_to? :each. This is probably not the canonical way. I suggest just returning an empty string or [] as the response body instead.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but for the users googling and using this later on: Beware that this will probably make your tests fail in weird ways as the DEFAULT_HOST for rspec tests is "www.example.com" and all requests will get redirected, even within your tests!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In **Ruby on Rails 4**, removing www. from any URL whilst maintaining the pathname can be achieved simply by using:

```
# config/routes.rb

constraints subdomain: 'www' do
  get ':any', to: redirect(subdomain: nil, path: '/%{any}'), any: /.*/
end
```

In contrast, adding www. to the beginning of any URL that doesn't already have it can be achieved by:

```
# config/routes.rb

constraints subdomain: false do
  get ':any', to: redirect(subdomain: 'www', path: '/%{any}'), any: /.*/
end
```

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted for Rails 4 users. If you're using rails `<= 3`, please see some of the other answers in this thread.

Comment: This is pretty awesome!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's something that I'm doing but when using the `constraints subdomain: false`, it actually does two redirects for some reason and ends up in `www.www.localhost:3000`. In the browser I can see it redirected `localhost:3000` => `www.localhost:3000` => `www.www.localhost:3000`

Comment: The reason it wasn't working is because the router checks for a TLD and domain name such that `localhost` and `www.localhost` do not have subdomains.

Comment: I want to redirect ONLY if the subdomain is empty, if there is already a subdomain then don't redirect. possible?

Comment: I'd love to know where that `any: /.*/` is documented, because that is gold.

Comment: For those looking to match more than just get routes: match ':any', to: ..., via: :all (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

Answer (score 13):

There's a better approach if you're using Rails 3.  Just take advantage of the routing awesomeness.

```
Foo::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(:host => /^example.com/) do
    root :to => redirect("http://www.example.com")
    match '/*path', :to => redirect {|params| "http://www.example.com/#{params[:path]}"}
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to redirect **without** www when www is specified. Can you adapt your answer. I will mark it as accepted if it works. :)

Comment: is it also possible you could make it domain agnostic? E.g., something like `"#{params[:protocol]}://#{params[:host]}/#{params[:path]}"` ?

Answer (score 12):

I really like using the Rails Router for such things.  Previous answers were good, but I wanted something general purpose I can use for any url that starts with "www".

I think this is a good solution:

```
constraints(:host => /^www\./) do
  match "(*x)" => redirect { |params, request|
    URI.parse(request.url).tap {|url| url.host.sub!('www.', '') }.to_s
  }
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this middleware, it should do precisely what you want:

http://github.com/iSabanin/www_ditcher

Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: Ilya, I'm marking this as accepted but I came up with a slightly more elegant/robust solution. According to the [Rack Spec](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html), "The Body itself should not be an instance of String, as this will break in Ruby 1.9." So, I made an adjustment here. Also, I'm using Rack::Request object for handling the URL and making the code a little cleaner.

Answer (score 7):

A one-line version of Duke's solution. Just add to the top of routes.rb

```
match '(*any)' => redirect { |p, req| req.url.sub('www.', '') }, :constraints => { :host => /^www\./ }
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you also make another version to include redirect from onedomain.com to onedomain.net for example? If the both domains share the same name, could it be like req.url.sub('www.','').sub('net','com') ?

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 3

```
#config/routes.rb
Example::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(:host => "www.example.net") do
    match "(*x)" => redirect { |params, request|
      URI.parse(request.url).tap { |x| x.host = "example.net" }.to_s
    }
  end
  # .... 
  # .. more routes ..
  # ....
end
```

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I've have the relevant code within my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to redirect from the top-level domain (TLD) to the www subdomain, use this code:

```
constraints :subdomain => '' do
  match '(*any)' => redirect { |p, req| req.url.sub('//', '//www.') }
end
```

Note: This code the use of sub, not gsub, because sub replaces the first occurrence of the double-slashes where gsub would replace all double-slashes.

Comment: An answer to the reverse of this question, but very useful - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For Rails 4 the above solutions have to be appended with the Verb construction e.g. `via: [:get, :post]`.  Duke's solution becomes:

```
  constraints(:host => /^www\./) do
    match "(*x)" => redirect { |params, request|
      URI.parse(request.url).tap {|url| url.host.sub!('www.', '') }.to_s
    }, via: [:get, :post]
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with the approaches above, but there are also a couple of gems that provide Rack middleware to do this.

I like the way that they keep this behaviour separate from the app itself, but it's not a particularly strong argument either way. I also use middleware to do this when working with Sinatra, so prefer to use a technique that I can use on apps built from Rails and/or Sinatra (I often run Nesta embedded in Rails).

Anyway, here they are:

- https://github.com/cwninja/rack-force_domain
- https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host

The first is simpler (and the one I've been using) while the second offers a couple more features (that I'm yet to need, but appreciate).