# Redirect from "mysite.herokuapp.com" to "www.mysite.com"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, http-redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure heroku application DNS to Godaddy Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain)

I purchased a domain from GoDaddy, say it's www.mysite.com, and I am hosting my app on Heroku mysite.herokuapp.com. When I click on mysite.herokuapp.com it should redirect-to www.mysite.com, my site to various pages (e.g. myapp.herokuapp.com/users)from code or similar but (mysite.herokuapp.com shuld not be accessible)

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it inside your Rails application.

Create a Rack middleware that inspects the `HTTP_HOST` variable.
If the value doesn't match `www.mysite.com`, then send a redirect status code and redirect the user to the right path.

Here's a few examples you can start from to get an idea

- [How to redirect without www using Rails 3 / Rack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046960/how-to-redirect-without-www-using-rails-3-rack)
- https://github.com/stjhimy/rack-www