# Forwarding default heroku domain to another default heroku domain

Tags: heroku

I need to forward my default heroku domain http://app1name.herokuapp.com to http://app2name.herokuapp.com ?  Is this possible with heroku?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Redirect from "mysite.herokuapp.com" to "www.mysite.com"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471433), you probably need functionality in that app (`app1name`) to redirect requests to `app2name` - preferably with a `HTTP 302` or `301` response.