# Redirecting www to non-www for https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ssl, heroku, https

So, my registered common name for SSL is a non-www address. I have successfully redirected `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`, but `www.example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com` rather than the non-www https address even though I have created a redirect (using Namecheap) with a source URL:

```
www.example.com
```

and a destination URL:

```
https://example.com
```

To further clarify, in the Advanced DNS section, I have a URL Redirect Record with Host

```
www
```

and value

```
https://example.com
```

This is a Rails app running on Heroku. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting in the routes (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19426889/637094)? Those DNS redirects are simply tricks performed on a server the DNS own, I wouldn't trust them much.

Comment: Just tried, did not fix.