# Prepend www. to my Rails app url through Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am new to Nginx and looking out for a configuration to prepend 'www.' to my rails application url.

For example, if a user submits `example.com` into the browser url section the nginx should rewrite the url as `www.example.com` and redirect.

Kindly help me achieve this.

> Edit

The linked question's answers doesn't serve my requirement since the approach suggested is related to Apache and redirection is performed through `ApplicationController`. I request the StackOverflow Community members to interfere, remove the negative reputation points and grant me the required permission to ask more questions.

Comment: Majunath, what web server are using in production server, apache or nginx?

Comment: Ramesh, I'm using nginx server

Comment: Oh ok, have you tried this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706247/redirect-non-www-requests-to-www-urls-in-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Nginx`

```
server{
 listin 80;
 server_name xyz.com;
 rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.xyz.com$1;
}
```

Comment: @Manjunath P: As you are using `nginx server`, the answer which I had given definitely work!!!. let us know if you have any issue.

Comment: It works, Thanks @Vinay

Comment: @Manjunath P: Glad It helps .