# Redirect domain to www.domain with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

*Hello*,
Im new with Ruby on Rails and I would like to add some properties to redirect automatly my **domain.com** to **www.domain.com**

I've looked at existed closed issues but everythings work with .htaccess, but I dont have it with Rails.

**EDIT:**

Saw this link : [Redirect non-www requests to www urls in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706247/redirect-non-www-requests-to-www-urls-in-rails)
But seems not updated, I got this error using the code in answer (**request_uri** not found)

**EDIT II**

From http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Http/URL/request_uri I saw we have to use now **request.url**

Tried it and got wrong URL using the following code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :add_www_subdomain

  private
  def add_www_subdomain
    unless /^www/.match(request.host)
      redirect_to("#{request.protocol}x.com#{request.url}",
                  :status => 301)
    end
  end
end
```

My domain becomes also strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself, the following code is gonna add www. to your url if there are not into.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :add_www_subdomain

  private
  def add_www_subdomain
    unless /^www/.match(request.host)
      redirect_to("#{request.url}".gsub("#{request.protocol}", "#{request.protocol}www."), status: 301)
    end
  end
end
```